# Access to SSL site

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal.
How can I access to SSL sites?
I Used this code to post my HTTPS uri:

```
    public async Task<string> SignIn()
    {
        string pageSource = "";
        string url = Site.Ecare + Site.GetSubAddress(SubAddress.Login);
        string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", Site.Username, Site.Password);
        formParams = Uri.EscapeUriString(formParams);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formParams);

        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.;
        request.Method = "Post";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (Stream os = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            pageSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch {  }

        return pageSource;
    }
```

but it gaves me this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in MyAppName.WindowsPhone.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'MyAppName.WindowsPhone.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'.
```

Execption:

```
Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Thanks

Comment: You have an empty `catch` block.  Catch the exception, and post the full details of the exception.

Comment: here is Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Are you hitting an endpoint that is using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: no it's not self-signed